# Apply border-spacing to table body rows only

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 2 header rows and multiple body rows. I want the spacing between rows in the body to be 10 pixels. I achieve this with:

```
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 10px;
```

However, this also obviously applies to the rows in the header. But for the header, I want there to be no space between the rows. My HTML is:

```css
table td {
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}
table th {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5osx023r/1/). I want there to be no space between the bottom of the first header row and top of second header row. I've tried applying `border-spacing` just to the body but it only works at table level. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

*As an old question but redundant,*

you may use `transform`, `box-shadow` or `position` to **fake** collapsing in between 2 rows (or more ):

- transform :

```css
table td {
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

table th {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

thead tr:first-of-type {
  transform: translatey(10px)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- position :

```css
table td {
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

table th {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

thead tr:first-of-type {
  position:relative;
  top:10px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- box-shadow :

```css
table td {
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

table th {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

thead tr:first-of-type th {
  box-shadow:0 10px red
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `border-spacing` is applied to [**table elements**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-spacing) and can not be targeted for `tbody` alone but you can try the below CSS hack and apply `border: white` to the `td` element to create a margin effect.

**Additional Code:**

```
table td {
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```css
table td {
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
table th {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works in the snippet right? How are you using this in your code?

Comment: Is this how you need it? http://prntscr.com/8771i5 Works in FF. I will try to customize it for cross-browser.

Comment: I hate the browser wars :D

Answer (score 0):

try to make a class in CSS using padding/border-spacing

```
.tableClass>tbody>tr>td {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}
```

this usually works for me

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table th{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 12px;
}
  
.table td {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 12px;
}
.tablerow {
  border-bottom: 20px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
      <tr class="tablerow">
          <th>head 1</th>
          <th>head 1</th>
          <th>head 1</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>    
  <tbody>
      <tr class="tablerow">
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tablerow">
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It's working fine. It puts a border of 20px in the bottom of the rows that can be used as a spacing between rows and you can apply full border also.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html

Answer (score -1):

I think  this how you can achieve.

```css
table.test td {
    background-color: lime;
    //margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
   padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

table.test th{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

table.test tbody{
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  position:absolute; 
  *border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing = '10px');
}
```

```html
<table class="test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>head 1</th>
            <th>head 1</th>
            <th>head 1</th>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <th>head 2</th>
            <th>head 2</th>
            <th>head 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

below is the updated jsfiddle

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5osx023r/3/)**

Comment: Nice try but im not going to use this method, position:absolute on the tbody throughs off the algnment of columns in the table

Comment: @Mark so what are your mandatory conditions .? please update in question so that i as well as others can try out other thing

Comment: well I dont want the alignment of the table to be thrown off, columns should stay as columns. With above css, that wont be the case